# Is it possible to catch the change in resolution of streaming video of webRTC?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

we are doing a project on webRTC,and we have some requirement which need us to catch the event when the resolution of streaming video(remote stream) changes in WEB RTC is there any possible way by which we can achieve this??

thanks in Advance for your help

Comment: I don't think there's an event for that, but there is a getUserMedia() function that returns a constraints object containing the resolution, and you'd probably have to poll that in an interval or something

Comment: getUserMedia does not *return* the constraints object. You pass it to the function. There is no way of getting notified. The size/bitrate will be adjusted overtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the <video> elements onresize function is called and you can check the .videoWidth and .videoHeight properties.

See [this demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/) and the source in [lines 36-38](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/js/main.js#L36-38).

Comment: The onresize handler **is not called**, when I stream from iOS (11.4) to a Chrome (67) on Desktop or Android (5 or 6).
 
It **is called** when streaming from iOS to iOS or between Chrome and Android or between Android devices.

Comment: that typically indicates an error such as incompatible codecs or a failing network connection. Check chrome://webrtc-internals and look for errors

Comment: I don't see any errors. The video is working well, I just don't receive the event. I circumvented it by sending a socket message and adding a handler to it. In my case I am trying to catch orientation changes after device rotation. The initial `onloadedmetadata`, maybe even `onresize`, seems to trigger in all cases.